# How to compress a UIImage in order to send it to a server faster

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, nsfilemanager, imageurl

I need to send an image to a server in chunks of 512 bytes.

I am getting the image with:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    [weakViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    UIImage *shareImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
 imageData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(shareImage);

    imageURL = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] absoluteString];


    imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%d.png",[StorageManager sharedManager].storagePath, (int)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
    [imageData writeToFile:imageURL atomically:YES];

 NSString *imageUri = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%d.jpg",[StorageManager sharedManager].storagePath, (int)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
    [imageData writeToFile:imageUri atomically:YES];
}
```

//get the image

```
fileData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:imageURL];

        file=[[message.fileURL pathComponents] lastObject];
```

Is there a way to **COMPRESS** the image (make the fileData smaller) in order to minimize the timpe the chunks get to the destination?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to create the file representation of the `UIImage` object. This will produce a large file with photos. Try using JPEG file format with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and adjust the compression quality to reduce the file size.

Comment: Could you refactor my code with .jpeg? If I retrieve from Photo library a file .jpeg can i reduce the size drastically? Could you please give me an example based on what i ve post? Thank you!